# How can i install opencv contrib on arm (pydroid3)

Tags: python, opencv

So i tried so many to install opencv-contrib-python
But it failed

And i tried use

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.25
```

And it failed too
Show that :-

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.25
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.25
```

Comment: "failed" how, exactly?

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python @ForceBru